# Reactjs - Update state in child component when parent componend state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I have this setup:

Parent Component = 
Child Component =

Parent component:

```
this.state = {
      tags: [],
      activeFilter: {}
    };
```

and a method:

```
removeTag = (data) => {
    const newData = this.state.tags.slice();
    const indexToRemove = this.state.tags.indexOf(data);
    newData.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    this.setState({
      tags: newData
    });
  }
```

Now, I would like when parent method occurs to update state inside child component:

```
this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
    };
```

this "suggestions" array.

This is my render method from parent component:

```
render() {

    const {title} = this.props;
    const {tags, activeFilter} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="search">
        <div>
          <h1 className="search__title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: title}}></h1>

          <div className="search__wrapper">
            <form id="SearchForm"
              action="#"
              name="SearchComponent"
              autoComplete="false"
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

              <ul id="token-list" className="flex">

                {
                    tags.map((item) => (
                        <Tag data={item} key={item.id} removeTag={this.removeTag} />
                    ))
                }

                <li className="flex__input flex--inline flex--grow">
                  <Input onInputUpdate={this.updateCallback} filter={activeFilter} />
                  <button type="submit" className="input-icon">
                    <span className="icon ion-ios-search"></span>
                  </button>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Not related to your question but don't ever use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if you don't really really really really need to. From your code as I understand you are just passing a string so you can just do `<h1 className="search__title">{title}</h1>`. Second note, I can see that you are changing tags in state. This triggers a re-render for the child components (Tag).

Comment: for your question "update state in child component when parent state changes" you can pass functions as props to child component and execute them in child component

Comment: @bennygenel I needed this because I have HTML tags inside a string.

Comment: @PranayKumar can you give me an example please?

Comment: i did not get your issue, honestly. Why do you need to save props into local state of child component. Reveal your child component code please

Comment: `removeTag(tag) => this.setState({ tags: this.state.tags.filter(item => item !== tag) })` pretending that tag is type of string

Comment: You can pass html tags as stateless components with your props. There is 99% of the time alternative to using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Do a little bit of a research and you can definitely find it.

Comment: @IslamIbakaev I have a method inside Parent component and whenever that method is called I want to update array inside Child component bind to this.state.

Comment: can you please show child component?

Comment: @IslamIbakaev https://pastebin.com/isL1kQnJ

Answer (score 0):

no need to keep "suggestions" array state inside `<Input />`
you'd better lift this state up to parent component.

and then update to this

```
<Input 
  suggestions = {this.state.suggestions}
  onInputUpdate={this.updateCallback} 
  filter={activeFilter} 
/>
```

And, of course, you need to update your `<Input />` component code accordingly.